# Polymer LitElement & Angular - render never called, no content displayed

Tags: angular, polymer, lit-element

I want to use Polymers LitElement in my Angular application.

For that, I created an example component (`test.js`) in the `assets` folder of my application, and imported it in the `index.html`.

test.js:

```js
// Import the LitElement base class and html helper function
import { LitElement, html } from '../../../node_modules/lit-element/lit-element';

// Extend the LitElement base class
class Test extends LitElement {

  render(){
    return html`
      <h1>Test works!</h1>
    `;
  }
}
// Register the new element with the browser.
customElements.define('ti8m-test', Test);
```

index.html:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgInAction</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script type="module" src="/assets/comp-new/default/src/ti8m/test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I installed `lit-element` in the comp-new directory, using `npm install --prefix ./ lit-element`.

I also did a `npm install lit-element` in the project itself, so the npm module is definitely available.

However, when I run my Angular application using `ng serve`, and navigate to the URL where I included my test component, I find my component in the DOM (using the inspector), but there is no content displayed.
Also, when I put a `console.log` into the `render` function, I never see the output in the browser. So it looks like the method is never actually called.

Here's how it looks in the DOM:

[image]

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright. Once again, solving my own problems, hoping to help anyone with a similar issue ;)

**First off:** My approach was not the best. I wouldn't recommend putting your custom elements into the assets folder. Usually you would get your custom elements by installing an npm module, so I moved the components into the project structure. Like this, I could also get rid of the additional node_modules and the imports got a lot easier to handle.

How to use Lit Element Custom Components in Angular:

1. Install lit-elemnt in your project: `npm install --save lit-element`
2. Create a folder in your `src/app` folder for all the custom components (i.e. `custom-components`)
3. Create your component (JS or TS, I chose TS)

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

// Extend the LitElement base class
// export the class, so it can be imported where it is needed
export class Ti8mTestComponent extends LitElement {

  /**
   * Implement `render` to define a template for your element.
   *
   * You must provide an implementation of `render` for any element
   * that uses LitElement as a base class.
   */
  render() {
    /**
     * `render` must return a lit-html `TemplateResult`.
     *
     * To create a `TemplateResult`, tag a JavaScript template literal
     * with the `html` helper function:
     */

    console.log('test-component', this);
    return html`
      <h1>Test works!</h1>
      <p>For real though!</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

Notice how I left out the `customElements.define('ti8m-test', Ti8mTestComponent)` part. We'll get to this in a second.

4. You can define your custom elements wherever you want in your code. I suggest either `main.ts`, an NgModule, or in the constructor of the component where you want to use the element.

   `import {Ti8mTestComponent} from './app/custom-elements/ti8m/test';
   ...
   customElements.define('ti8m-test', Ti8mTestComponent);`

That's it! Your Lit Element should be visible in your application now! :-)

**Notes:**

1. I had to update to Angular 7, since that's the first version to use Typescript > 3, which is needed for the Lit Element npm module. (Lit Element is using type `unknown` in its code, which was introduced by Typescript 3)
2. Also I had to change the `target` in `tsconfig.json` to `es2015`. (otherwise you'll run into `class constructors must be invoked with |new|` console errors)

Have fun! I hope it helps.

Comment: In addition to 4: you can also use decorators to define your elements, just put `@customElement('ti8m-test')` on the line before "export class...". 
In my opinion this is better than defining them in main.ts because it looks more coherent (to me)